# SQL - To Check if Placement exists in both data sources

Tags: sql

[image]

This is a tabular view of the dataset. In count column, I want to return output if the placement is present in both Data Sources i.e. 'DBM' and 'DCM' or not.

I worked on Select query with which I grouped the Data by Data Source and Placement column and then I counted the placements, if it is 1 then it is only in one data source if it is 2 then it is in both data sources, but I'm not able to convert it into the update query.

Select Query -

```
Select placement, COUNT(placement)

from (select placement from [dataset1]

      group by placement, data_source
     ) 
group by placement
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your query as below:

```
select placement, count(distinct datasource)
from [dataset1]
group by placement
```

Answer (score 0):

using these 2 tables:

```
create table dataset1(
    Date date,
    Data_source varchar(3),
    Placement varchar(15),
    count int
)

create table dataset2(
    id int identity(1,1),
    Placement varchar(15)
)

create table dataset3(
    id int identity(1,1),
    Placement varchar(15)
)
```

and these data:

```
dataset1
Date        Data_source Placement   count
1900-01-01  DBM         Placement1  (NULL)
1900-01-02  DCM         Placement1  (NULL)
1900-01-03  DCM         Placement1  (NULL)
1900-01-04  DCM         Placement2  (NULL)
1900-01-05  DCM         Placement2  (NULL)

dataset2
id  Placement
1   Placement1

dataset3
id  Placement
1   Placement1
```

with this query:

```
update dataset1  set count=
(case when exists(select Placement from dataset2 b where b.placement=dataset1.placement) then 1 else 0 end )+
(case when exists(select Placement from dataset3 b where b.placement=dataset1.placement) then 2 else 0 end )
```

you obtain this result

```
  Date      Data_source Placement   count
1900-01-01  DBM         Placement1  3
1900-01-02  DCM         Placement1  3
1900-01-03  DCM         Placement1  3
1900-01-04  DCM         Placement2  0
1900-01-05  DCM         Placement2  0
```

Just for clarification

- 1=if placement exists in dataset2
- 2=if placement exists in dataset3
- 3=if placement exists in both

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` to count the amount of different data sources you have by placement. Then you can join your original data set with these results, also by placement.

```
UPDATE T SET
    Count = DistinctDataSources
FROM
    dataset1 AS T
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            D.Placement,
            COUNT(DISTINCT(D.DataSource)) AS DistinctDataSources
        FROM
            dataset1 AS D
        WHERE
            D.DataSource IN ('DBM', 'DCM')
        GROUP BY
            D.Placement
    ) AS P 
        ON T.Placement = P.Placement
```

You can remove the `WHERE` if you don't want to only count `DBM` and `DCM`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to return output if the placement is present in both Data Sources i.e. 'DBM' and 'DCM' or not.

I think you just want:

```
select placement
from dataset1
where data_source in ('DBM', 'DCM')
group by placement
having count(distinct data_source) = 2;
```

If you want the original data, then I would suggest `exists`:

```
select d.*
from dataset1 d
where exists (select 1
              from dataset1 d2
              where d2.placement = d.placement and
                    d2.data_source = 'DBM'
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from dataset1 d2
              where d2.placement = d.placement and
                    d2.data_source = 'DCM'
             );
```